# VNC server connection to guest os in virtual box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox, ubuntu-12.04, vnc, vnc-server

I have a ubuntu 12.04 host machine. Inside that machine i have a guest o.s installed using virtualbox. I have  installed a tight vnc server  (i am ready to change the VNC server if not possible in tightvnc) on my ubuntu host o.s. i am trying to connect to the vnc server through my vnc viewer. but i get a new x session opened for the host o.s  all i want is to just connect to the guest o.s  through vnc server on host o.s . Is this possible ? can any body explain me in detail how to do this.
p.s :- For some reason i dont want to install vnc server on my guest O.S ?.

Comment: This is more a question about [how to set up networking in VirtualBox](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/Networking), rather than how to use your VNC client or anything to do with programming. As a hint, read about "bridged networking" in the VirtualBox documentation. You'll need to assign another IP address for your guest, on a subnet shared with your host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the VirtualBox Expansion Pack from Oracle, it can be used freely for personal or evaluational purpose and provides an RDP server providing the real console output of the VM. You can also start the VM in background and access it through RDP - google for headless mode.

I know you want to use VNC, but RDP is (in my opinion) superior to VNC on any level and I use this setup very often and it works fine (from Win/Lin/Mac).